# QuerySyntaxException in Hybernate while using *

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am getting QuerySyntaxException while trying to execute this line of code,

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM t_student01";
```

This is how it looks like in the editor:
[image: ide]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your HQL syntax should either be:

```
SELECT t FROM YourEntityClass t
```

Or, you can actually omit the `SELECT` portion entirely:

```
FROM YourEntityClass
```

Comment: Well that was an SQL example from my teacher, and he ran it without any problem. So it should probably be in SQL syntax. Though I wanted to try your code and got this problem after: https://imgur.com/a/eeQiiqW